# gvim incorrect font (or encoding) in menu

Tags: gvim, microsoft-windows, font, encoding

I use 32bit gvim 7.4 on Win7 64bit CZ. I replaced the gettext and iconv libraries according to the guide on the vim website. I wanted to use utf-8 and have setup the `guifont`, `encoding` and `fileencoding` options. I use the Czech localization (which is somehow default, probably based on OS language). Up to this point, everything is working fine. The content of utf-8 encoded files is read, rendered and written as expected. Even the gvim messages (like warnings or infos) using the `guifont` renders as expected (in cs_CZ). But...

The application menu font is not able to render the international characters. Seems like it's using different encoding. Some characters are completely missing, some use weird symbols.

Is there any way, how to change the font/encoding the gvim.exe is using for the **menu rendering** (the menu bar also as the contextual "mouse" menu)?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like there is no easy way to change font/encoding for menu rendering. Maybe it's somewhere in the code files, and you need to change and compile it in order to be able to decode menu in another encoding.

I have the same issue (in Russian localization), I think it appears after adding in vimrc this:

```
set termencoding=utf-8 
set encoding=utf-8
set fileencodings=utf8,cp1251
```

Not sure which of them make this problem. So you can try to delete it, and maybe it will resolve the problems. But when you need to open the file in a different encoding, you will need to add ++end every time opening the file with other encodings.

So I resolved this just by switching to english in gvim. To do this you need to add at the top of vimrc this code:

```
set langmenu=en_US.UTF-8    " sets the language of the menu (gvim)
language en
```